# How to run glue script from Glue Dev Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a glue script (test.py) written say in a editor. I connected to glue dev endpoint and copied the script to endpoint or I can store in S3 bucket. Basically glue endpoint is an EMR cluster, now how can I run the script from the dev endpoint terminal? Can I use spark-submit and run it ?

I know we can run it from glue console,but more interested to know if I can run it from glue end point terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a notebook; you can ssh to the dev endpoint and run it with the `gluepython` interpreter (not plain `python`).

e.g.

```
radix@localhost:~$ DEV_ENDPOINT=glue@ec2-w-x-y-z.compute-1.amazonaws.com
radix@localhost:~$ scp myscript.py $DEV_ENDPOINT:/home/glue/myscript.py
radix@localhost:~$ ssh -i {private-key} $DEV_ENDPOINT
...
[glue@ip-w-x-y-z ~]$ gluepython myscript.py
```

You can also run the script directly without getting an interactive shell with ssh (of course, after uploading the script with `scp` or whatever):

```
radix@localhost:~$ ssh -i {private-key} $DEV_ENDPOINT gluepython myscript.py
```

If this is a script that uses the `Job` class (as the auto-generated Python scripts do), you may need to pass `--JOB_NAME` and `--TempDir` parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I was looking for. Let me try and I will let you know.

Answer (score 2):

For development / testing purpose, you can setup a zeppelin notebook locally, have an SSH connection established using the AWS Glue endpoint URL, so you can have access to the data catalog/crawlers,etc. and also the s3 bucket where your data resides.

After all the testing is completed, you can bundle your code, upload to an S3 bucket. Then create a Job pointing to the ETL script in S3 bucket, so that the job can be run, and scheduled as well.

Please refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-local-notebook.html) and [setting up zeppelin on windows](https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/apache-zeppelin-installation-on-windows-10/), for any help on setting up local environment.  You can use dev instance provided by Glue, but you may incur additional costs for the same(EC2 instance charges).

Once you set up the zeppelin notebook, you can copy the script(test.py) to the zeppelin notebook, and run from the zeppelin.

According to AWS Glue FAQ:

> Q: When should I use AWS Glue vs. Amazon EMR?
>
> AWS Glue works on top of the Apache Spark environment to provide a
>   scale-out execution environment for your data transformation jobs. AWS
>   Glue infers, evolves, and monitors your ETL jobs to greatly simplify
>   the process of creating and maintaining jobs. Amazon EMR provides you
>   with direct access to your Hadoop environment, affording you
>   lower-level access and greater flexibility in using tools beyond
>   Spark.

Do you have any specific requirement to run Glue script in an EMR instance?  Since in my opinion, EMR gives more flexibility and you can use any 3rd party python libraries and run directly in a EMR Spark cluster.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am more looking into how to run the glue script after logging in (ssh) to GLUE/EMR cluster with out the use of console/notebook

Comment: AWS Glue is serverless or a managed services, wherein I dont think we get access to SSH to the EC2 instance for the AWS Glue DevEndpoint at all.  If you need to login to the terminal, and like to have more control on the way the scripts to be run, EMR would be the best option.  Please note that GLUE/EMR are not the same, see my updated answer.