# AWS Glue - Access new dev endpoint from existing notebook server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, endpoint, apache-zeppelin, aws-glue

I would like to be able to connect already created Apache Zeppelin notebook server to new endpoint.

So, I create endpoint and then Zeppelin notebook server on that endpoint and everything works fine. At the end of the day, I delete this endpoint and STOP instance server running so no extra cost occurs. At this moment, I would like to start this instance and connect to new endpoint. What do I have to change to do this? My guess is change some config file to point to new endpoint and upload public key to newly created endpoint?

Comment: did u find answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way for this would be set up a local zeppelin server on your laptop, and connect to the development end point that is setup every day.  Just create ssh connection between the Glue Dev End Point, and the zeppelin using the Glue DEP URL available on the Glue console.  Please refer to this links for more info on setting up local zeppelin server, etc.

[Reference for setting up local zeppelin server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431504/how-to-run-glue-script-from-glue-dev-endpoint/50442853#50442853)

Let me know if you face any issues.