# How to connect Spark Development Environment to AWS Glue Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, aws-glue

I want to create development environment to run Spark app written in Scala to AWS Glue endpoint. What is my best option? I'm using Windows 10 and I've tried connecting Apache Zeppelin(running on docker) to Glue endpoint, but did not manage to do it.

Can I connect Glue endpoint with IntelliJ running Spark app localy on my machine?

Comment: POSSIBLE DUPLICATE OF https://stackoverflow.com/a/49256812/647053

Comment: some one already raised the ticket with aws support team it seems there is no inbuilt support like pycharm in case of python

Comment: Though i am not sure about intellij, I have many times setup Zeppelin on my laptop and was successful to connect to AWS Glue service.  Please refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431504/how-to-run-glue-script-from-glue-dev-endpoint/50442853#50442853.  The link has further references to setup required software, environment settings, and running Zeppelin in local laptop, and connecting to AWS glue to develop & run your pyspark codes